# MySQL: Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedures in MySQL. Why is the beginning of my stored procedure...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS videodb.addVideo;
CREATE PROCEDURE videodb.addVideo(vidTitle VARCHAR(255), vidDescription VARCHAR(500), producerArray VARCHAR(500), actorArray VARCHAR(500), OUT vidSuccess BOOL)
    START TRANSACTION;
            SET @videoInsertVar = 'INSERT INTO videodb.videos (id, title, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';
            SET @videoId = NULL;
            SET @videoTitle = vidTitle; -- this is line 69
```

...producing this strange error...

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 69: Unknown column 'vidTitle' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Wrap in `BEGIN`-`END` That will make *body* a single statement. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Right you are. I originally had a `BEGIN ... END` but I misinterpreted the documentation. I thought this meant you should use `START TRANSACTION` in place of `BEGIN ... END`, but now I understand: "Within all stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events), the parser treats BEGIN [WORK] as the beginning of a BEGIN ... END block. To begin a transaction in this context, use START TRANSACTION instead."

Comment: @PM77-1 If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the statement that throws the error is actually **outside** of your procedure and, thus, - outside of its parameters scope.  The solution is to wrap the entire ***routine_body*** of the procedure into a `BEGIN ... END` structure to create a [`Compound Statement`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html).

[`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) expects a "*Valid SQL routine statement*" in its body. Using the Compound-Statement Syntax allows to group multiple statements into a single code-block and comply with this requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `IN`-denoting that the input parameter, and I hope you have an `END`-at the last line.

Try some changes like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE videodb.addVideo(IN vidTitle VARCHAR(255), IN vidDescription VARCHAR(500), IN producerArray VARCHAR(500), IN actorArray VARCHAR(500), OUT vidSuccess BOOL)
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;
            SET @videoInsertVar = 'INSERT INTO videodb.videos (id, title, description) VALUES(?, ?, ?)';
            SET @videoId = NULL;
            SET @videoTitle = vidTitle; -- this is line 69
```

Also make sure that you have set the `DELIMITER`, otherwise `;` will be treated as the end of the stored procedure.

Comment: Actually, each parameter is an `IN` parameter by default. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: And you missed the next line:

Specifying a parameter as IN, OUT, or INOUT is valid only for a PROCEDURE. For a FUNCTION, parameters are always regarded as IN parameters.

Comment: I didn't miss that line; however, you evidently misunderstand it. That line, to put it another way, is merely stating that you cannot specify `OUT` or `INOUT` for functions.